# Failed depth_image_proc build on OSX

Tags: ros, macos, ros-fuerte, macos-lion, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having a problem getting depth_image_proc to compile on OSX 10.7.3 for Fuerte. I forked rosdistro and added a homebrew line for pcl (which is installed ... 1.5.1), but it still fails. Any thoughts?

[kevin@dhcp184-48-194-60 depth_image_proc]$ rosmake depth_image_proc
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['depth_image_proc']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /Users/kevin/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120426-082529
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['depth_image_proc'] to:
['depth_image_proc']
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosservice ROS_NOBUILD in package rosservice
No Makefile in package rosservice
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang
No Makefile in package roslang
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospy ROS_NOBUILD in package rospy
No Makefile in package rospy
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp
No Makefile in package roscpp
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< sensor_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package sensor_msgs
No Makefile in package sensor_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> opencv2 [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< opencv2 [PASS] [ 0.05 seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> image_geometry [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure [PASS] [ 8.49 seconds ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosbuild ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbuild
No Makefile in package rosbuild
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib
No Makefile in package roslib
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosconsole ROS_NOBUILD in package rosconsole
No Makefile in package rosconsole
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< image_geometry [PASS] [ 10.57 seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_filters ROS_NOBUILD in package message_filters
No Makefile in package message_filters
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> bond [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< pluginlib [PASS] [ 4.51 seconds ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> image_transport [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< bond [PASS] [ 2.70 seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> smclib [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< smclib [PASS] [ 0.08 seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> bondcpp [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< bondcpp [PASS] [ 2.98 seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> nodelet [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< image_transport [PASS] [ 3.76 seconds ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosbag ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbag
No Makefile in package rosbag
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< geometry_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package geometry_msgs
No Makefile in package geometry_msgs
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< std_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_msgs
No Makefile in package std_msgs
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> bullet [ make ]
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package bullet written to:tive 20/31 Complete ]
[ rosmake ]    /Users/kevin/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120426-082529/bullet/build_output.log
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< bullet [PASS] [ 2.04 seconds ] -- WARNING: 4 compiler warnings
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> angles [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< angles [PASS] [ 2.00 seconds ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rostest ROS_NOBUILD in package rostest
No Makefile in package rostest
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roswtf [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roswtf ROS_NOBUILD in package roswtf
No Makefile in package roswtf
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> tf [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< nodelet [PASS] [ 5.03 seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> nodelet_topic_tools [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< nodelet_topic_tools [PASS] [ 2.89 seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> common_rosdeps [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< common_rosdeps [PASS] [ 0.39 seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> stereo_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< stereo_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package stereo_msgs
No Makefile in package stereo_msgs
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< tf [PASS] [ 6.79 seconds ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> pcl_ros [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< pcl_ros [SKIP] No rule to make target None
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> depth_image_proc [ make ]
[ rosmake ] All 35 linesepth_image_proc: 3.4 sec ]   [ 1 Active 30/31 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
[rosbuild] Building package depth_image_proc
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/rospy/rosbuild/rospy.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/common-lisp/ros/roslisp/rosbuild/roslisp.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/roscpp/rosbuild/roscpp.cmake
-- Eigen found (include: /usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.0.5/include/eigen3)
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
CMake Warning:
Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

```
  CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE
```

### -- Build files have been written to: /Users/kevin/ros_sandbox/stacks/image_pipeline/depth_image_proc/build
cd build && make -l2
[  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
[  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
Linking CXX shared library ../lib/libdepth_image_proc.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"boost::signals::connection::~connection()", referenced from:
message_filters::Connection::~Connection()in disparity.o
message_filters::Connection::~Connection()in point_cloud_xyzrgb.o
message_filters::Connection::~Connection()in register.o
"boost::signals::connection::operator=(boost::signals::connection const&)", referenced from:
void message_filters::Synchronizer<message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<sensor_msgs::Image_std::allocator<void >, sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_std::allocator<void >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType> >::connectInput<image_transport::SubscriberFilter, message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_std::allocator<void > >, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType> >(image_transport::SubscriberFilter&, message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_std::allocator<void > >&, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>&, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>&, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>&, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>&, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>&, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>&, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>&)in disparity.o
void message_filters::Synchronizer<message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<sensor_msgs::Image_std::allocator<void >, sensor_msgs::Image_std::allocator<void >, sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_std::allocator<void >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType> >::connectInput<image_transport::SubscriberFilter, image_transport::SubscriberFilter, message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_std::allocator<void > >, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType> >(image_transport::SubscriberFilter&, image_transport::SubscriberFilter&, message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_std::allocator<void > >&, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>&, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>&, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>&, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>&, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>&, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>&)in point_cloud_xyzrgb.o
void message_filters::Synchronizer<message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<sensor_msgs::Image_std::allocator<void >, sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_std::allocator<void >, sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_std::allocator<void >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType> >::connectInput<image_transport::SubscriberFilter, message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_std::allocator<void > >, message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_std::allocator<void > >, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType> >(image_transport::SubscriberFilter&, message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_std::allocator<void > >&, message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_std::allocator<void > >&, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>&, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>&, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>&, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>&, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>&, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>&)in register.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [../lib/libdepth_image_proc.dylib] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/depth_image_proc.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package depth_image_proc written to:
[ rosmake ]    /Users/kevin/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120426-082529/depth_image_proc/build_output.log
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< depth_image_proc [FAIL] [ 3.50 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package depth_image_proc.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 31 packages with 1 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /Users/kevin/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120426-082529

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32706/failed-depth_image_proc-build-on-osx/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2012-04-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured it out ... it is another boost linking error. Fuerte, OSX, and boost don't seem to always work like it does in linux.

Follow these [instructions](http://ros.org/doc/api/rosdep2/html/contributing_rules.html) to update pcl dependencies for osx.

Add the following lines to CMakeLists.txt in depth_image_proc:

```
rosbuild_add_boost_directories()
rosbuild_link_boost(depth_image_proc thread signals)
```

Then it will compile correctly. You will also need to change pcl from a package to a rosdep in manifest.xml.

You also need to do similar things in bondcpp and image_view if you get errors there.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2